# imac freezes after running program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, freeze

I am doing work with the training graphics library mlx. While testing the library, I ran into the problem that this code is causing my imac mojave to freeze. Only reboot helps. What's wrong?

My code

```
#include "./minilibx/mlx.h"
#include <math.h>
typedef struct  s_data
{
    void        *img;
    char        *addr;
    int         bits_per_pixel;
    int         line_length;
    int         endian;
}               t_data;
void            my_mlx_pixel_put(t_data *data, int x, int y, int color)
{
    char    *dst;
    dst = data->addr + (y * data->line_length + x * (data->bits_per_pixel / 8));
    *(unsigned int*)dst = color;
}
void DrawCircle(t_data *img, int x, int y, int r)
 {
       static const double PI = 3.1415926535;
       double i, angle, x1, y1;
       for(i = 0; i < 360; i += 0.1)
       {
             angle = i;
             x1 = r * cos(angle * PI / 180);
             y1 = r * sin(angle * PI / 180);
          my_mlx_pixel_put(img, x1 + x, y1 + y, 0x00FF0000);
       }
}

int     main(void)
{
    void    *mlx;
    void    *mlx_win;
    t_data  img;
    int     x = 0, y = 0;
    mlx = mlx_init();
    mlx_win = mlx_new_window(mlx, 1920, 1080, "Hello world!");
    img.img = mlx_new_image(mlx, 1920, 1080);
    img.addr = mlx_get_data_addr(img.img, &img.bits_per_pixel, &img.line_length,
                                    &img.endian);
    DrawCircle(&img, x, y, 25);
    mlx_put_image_to_window(mlx, mlx_win, img.img, 0, 0);
    mlx_loop(mlx);
}
```

mlx_new_image()

```
void    *mlx_new_image(mlx_ptr_t *mlx_ptr, int width, int height)
{
  mlx_img_list_t        *newimg;

  //  if (mlx_ptr->win_list == NULL)
  //    return (NULL);  // need at leat one window created to have openGL context and create texture
  if ((newimg = malloc(sizeof(*newimg))) == NULL)
    return ((void *)0);
  newimg->next = mlx_ptr->img_list;
  mlx_ptr->img_list = newimg;
  newimg->width = width;
  newimg->height = height;
  newimg->vertexes[0] = 0.0;  newimg->vertexes[1] = 0.0;
  newimg->vertexes[2] = width;  newimg->vertexes[3] = 0.0;
  newimg->vertexes[4] = width;  newimg->vertexes[5] = -height;
  newimg->vertexes[6] = 0.0;  newimg->vertexes[7] = -height;
  newimg->buffer = malloc(UNIQ_BPP*width*height);
  bzero(newimg->buffer, UNIQ_BPP*width*height);

  return (newimg);
}
```

Everything worked fine when x and y in main were x = 1000 and y = 500. But I changed them to zeros and everything started to freeze, with no way to stop anything. I always thought that when trying to interact with an unallocated memory cell, there would be a segfault, this provides security, but I seem to be wrong

Comment: If you draw a circle around the point `(0,0)` where do you draw the pixels that are outside of your screen/bitmap? Where do you check your limits?

Comment: I understand that this is a mistake. I don’t understand why the operating system didn’t prevent freezing

Comment: Operating systems can be buggy too.

Comment: Check bounds in DrawCircle

Comment: OT: regarding: `for(i = 0; i < 360; i += 0.1)`  Since the variable: `i` is a `double`, all the literals should also be `double`  I.E. `for(i = 0.0; i < 360.0; i += 0.1)